# Start Ordered List in HAML

Tags: css, html-lists, haml, css-counter

Trying to make this happen...

```
<ol start="5">
```

...but in HAML.

This doesn't work:

```
%ol{:start => "5"}
```

Any suggestions?

///Update Below - Added 14 Feb 2017///

After some digging around, I found that a previous developer had added this to the CSS:

```
ol>li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0 2rem;
  text-indent: -2rem;
  list-style-type:none;
  counter-increment:item;
}

ol>li:before {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-align:right;
  content:counter(item) ".";
}
```

What this basically does is remove the "normal" list item counters and replaces them with larger, bold font. It was a style choice by the original UX designer.

However, I'm not still not sure how to "start" the `counter(item)` (if that's indeed what I'm supposed to do).

Thanks!

Comment: That should work. What do you get instead?

Answer (score 1):

Aha - that is another story!

`list-style-type:none;` turns off the default HTML list styling from the list. This means that your `start` attribute won't do anything at all.

Now your previous developer are using fancy CSS to handle the list counter. Read more [about counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters). `content:counter(item) ".";` prints the counter for each item. `item` in this code is simply a name for the counter. You may want to have several counters on the same page. It will - naturally - start from 1. What you need to do is to reset the counter:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item 5;
}
```

and it should start from 5 instead of 1.